# In Django, how do I generate the CSRF input element while in a view?

Tags: django

In a Django template, I can use `{% csrf_token %}` to generate a hidden input element with the CSRF token as the value.

How do I do the same in a view? For instance,

```
def my_view(request):
  csrf_input = somehow_generate_csrf_token_input()
  return HttpResponse(csrf_input)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it), use the processor to generate the CSRF token:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def my_view(request):
    # csrf(request) returns a dict like {'csrf_token': 'xxx'}
    csrf_token = csrf(request)['csrf_token']
```